# Is it perfectly normal for PC to appear under two IP addresses if connected to the wifi and LAN at the same time?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I am a bit paranoid always on the lookout for intruders and that occurence had me bit worried. After quick nmap scan it turned out the 192.168.1.103 and 192.168.1.104 guy are the same pc - my laptop connected to the same network with wifi and lan. laptop is running ubuntu 20.04.

Is it perfectly normal or should i change some setup settings on the router ? Also etc hosts doesn't work that good for quick sshing into them cause ip assigned by router changes

Comment: yes, each device has its own IP, otherwise you would have an IP conflict.

Comment: most routers have the ability to apply static IPs so you can have always the same IP.

Comment: this is normal, each network interfance gets it own ip adress from your router unless specifically set otherwise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. This is perfectly normal.

Both the WiFi and the Ethernet devices are completely separate devices and has its own configuration and network address. They will have different MAC addresses as well.

Your router has no idea that two completely different network devices are actually the same computer, it shouldn't need to care.

The only issue may come if you specifically *want* your computer to use a specific interface to communicate over. Some software may end up using the Wifi, potentially dealing with a slower or slightly unreliable connection, while other software might use the Ethernet.

I would prefer ethernet over Wifi, and turn off or disable the wifi device on the computer when using  ethernet, but it is not a big deal.